# change string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am new to C# and not so expert in string manipulation. I have a string which represents the position of an object in diagram. The string contains integer values which I want to change for each object.

Example

```
String Position = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
```

I want to modify this string to

```
String Position = "l=50; r=190; t=-505; b=-555";
```

So if you notice t = -430 is changed to t = -505 and b = -480 to b = -555 which means an increment of -75 in both top and bottom

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You should parse the string into an object, change the values and reformat a string.

Comment: Can you modify source of string?

Comment: Oh, c'mon people. The question is not that bad for a newbie. Does not deserve all the downvotes!

Comment: @trailmax being a newbie does not exclude one from following [ask]. It's a question that shows zero research, so it does not deserve seven pity-upvotes.

Comment: @CodeCaster no, it does not deserve the pity-upvotes. But it does not deserve to be downvoted to oblivion either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a further explanation to [Jeroen van Langen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266130/jeroen-van-langen)'s comment

> You should parse the string into an object, change the values and reformat a string.

You can achieve this with a similar setup to this:

```
public class Position
{
    public int l { get; set; }
    public int r { get; set; }
    public int t { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"l = {l}, r = {r}, t = {t}, b = {b}";
    }
}
```

(Change the access modifiers to suit your needs)

And work with the object (simply) as below:

```
    public void UpdatePostion()
    {
        // Create new position
        Position pos = new Position
        {
            l = 50,
            r = 190,
            t = -430,
            b = -480
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"Pos before change: {pos.ToString()}");

        // change top and bottom value to accommodate increment
        pos.t += -75;
        pos.b += -75;

        // Prove that they've been updated
        Console.WriteLine($"Pos after change: {pos.ToString()}");
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to easily populate or modify the values in your input string, you can use [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
Position = string.Format("l={0}; r={1}; t={2}; b={3}", 50, 190, -430, -480);
```

You can extract the values of an existing input string using regular expressions, like this:

```
String Position = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
string pattern = @"^l=(\-{0,1}\d+); r=(\-{0,1}\d+); t=(\-{0,1}\d+); b=(\-{0,1}\d+)$";
var captGroups = Regex.Match(Position, pattern).Groups;
var l = captGroups[1];
var r = captGroups[2];
var t = captGroups[3];
var b = captGroups[4];
```

Comment: No, that skips the step of parsing the string in the first place.

Comment: @CodeCaster -- This question isn't about how to get the values out of the string, it's about how to change the string with new values.  "The string contains integer values which I want to change for each object."

Comment: Yes, and how does your answer show that? Your answer assumes the OP has the numbers in the first place, while the question assumes that the input is a string containing the number.

Comment: I'm reading the question differently than you, I guess. By my reading, the OP is populating the string with values and wants to know how to populate it with different values.

Comment: The question literally starts with _"I have a string"_.

Comment: It shouldn't be too rough to cover that base, Rory.  Just split it on ;, then spit those elements on = to recover the key/value pairs.

Comment: @CodeCaster -- Well, not *literally*... :)  It *literally* starts with "I am new to C#..."

Comment: @CodeCaster -- at any rate, I've attempted to improve the answer.

Comment: Well, yeah, I'll +1 even though you didn't do it the way I magnanimously suggested.  ; ^ )

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse your expression. Here is an example, in which the string is first splitted for `;` and then each part is splitted by `=`:

```
var position = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
var parts = position.Split(';'); // split string into 4 parts
var assignments = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var part in parts)
{
    var trimmedPart = part.Trim();
    var assignmentParts = trimmedPart.Split('='); // split each part into variable and value part
    var value = Int32.Parse(assignmentParts[1]); // convert string to integer value
    assignments.Add(assignmentParts[0], value);
}

// change values
assignments["t"] = -505;
assignments["b"] = -555;

// build new string
var newPosition = String.Join("; ", assignments.Select(p => p.Key + "=" + p.Value));
Console.WriteLine(">> " + newPosition);
```

Comment: was thinking along the same line but if the position gets duplicated then not sure how it will behave.

Comment: Looks like a rectangle definition - left, right, top, bottom - so presumably each value will be unique

Answer (score 1):

```
  String Position = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
  public void modifyPosition(int l, int r, int t, int b)
  {
     string[] parts = Position.Split(';');
     int oldL = int.Parse(parts[0].Replace("l=","").Trim());
     int oldR = int.Parse(parts[1].Replace("r=","").Trim());
     int oldT = int.Parse(parts[2].Replace("t=","").Trim());
     int oldB = int.Parse(parts[3].Replace("b=","").Trim());
     Position = "l="+(oldL+l).ToString()+"; r="+(oldR+r).ToString()+
     "; t="+(oldT+t).ToString()+"; b="+(oldB+b).ToString()+";";
  }
```

There are a lot of ways to generalize and optimize that -- I'll leave those up to you...

Answer (score 0):

So, building on one of the comments suggestions about parsing into an object - you could represent your Position object as follows:

```
public class Position
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Right { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Bottom { get; set; }
    public Position(string str)
    {
        int[] values = str.Split(new[] { "; " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
            .Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(s.IndexOf('=') +1))).ToArray();
        Left = values[0];
        Right = values[1];
        Top = values[2];
        Bottom = values[3];
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("; ", Left, Right, Top, Bottom);
    }
}
```

You could then use this object to serialize/deserialize your string to and from an object as follows:

```
string intputString = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
Position p = new Position(intputString);
p.Top -= 75;
p.Bottom -= 75;
string outputString = p.ToString();`
```

The only thing of any real complexity is turning your string into the object values. To do this we can delimit the string into each individual value by splitting the string on "; ". Each value can then be turned into an integer by taking the substring of each element after the equals character ("l=50" becomes "50") and converting it into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't usually want to manipulate data in string form unless the data is actually a string. In this case, you've really got a structure which is being represented as a string, so you should turn it into a structure first.

Based on the string you provided, this turns any string of a similar form into a dictionary.

```
var source = "l=50; r=190; t=-505; b=-555";
var components = source.Split(';').Select(x => x.Trim());
// components is now an enumerable of strings "l=50", "r=190" etc.
var pairs = components.Select(x => x.Split('=').ToArray());
// pairs is now an enumerable of arrays of strings ["l", "50"], ["r", "190"] etc;
var dictionary = pairs.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
// dictionary now contains r => 190, l => 50 etc.
```

Of course, you want to play with actual numbers, so you want to convert the values to integers really, so swap that last line out:

```
var dictionary = pairs.ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => Convert.ToInt32(x[1]));
```

Now you have a Dictionary which you can manipulate:

```
dictionary["t"] = dictionary["t"] - 75;
```

For example. Or you could use this as the basis of populating an object with appropriate properties and manipulate those.

```
struct Position {
    public int L { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
    public int T { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you might want to change it back into a string when you're done manipulating it:

```
var newString = string.Join("; ", dictionary.Select(x => $"{x.Key}={x.Value}"));
```

Although if you're planning to manipulate it a lot you should keep the parsed version around for as long as possible, as the parse/render cycle could be a performance issue if you do a lot of it.

Always store your data in appropriate types. Write new classes, write new structs, they don't have to be complicated but the more you can give names and shapes to your data the easier it is to manipulate it and to ensure that you manipulated it correctly.

This is all very simplistic of course - there's no error handling, such as if the value part isn't a valid Int32 (`Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception) or if there are duplicate keys (`ToDictionary` will throw an exception) etc. But hopefully it gives you some idea where to go.

It's also not the only way you could parse this kind of string, but it's fairly straightforward to follow and shouldn't be too slow, although it's not going to be very memory-efficient on a large input string.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/joNX2F).

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int r {get;set;}
    public int l {get;set;}
    public int t {get;set;}
    public int b {get;set;}

    public MyObject()
    {
    }

    public void ParseFromString(string val)
    {
        string[] splitVal = val.Split(';');     
        int intVal ;
        if(!int.TryParse(splitVal[0].Replace("l=","").Trim(), out intVal)) 
            intVal = 0;
        this.l = intVal;

        if(!int.TryParse(splitVal[1].Replace("r=","").Trim(), out intVal)) 
            intVal = 0;
        this.r = intVal;

        if(!int.TryParse(splitVal[2].Replace("t=","").Trim(), out intVal)) 
            intVal = 0;
        this.t = intVal;

        if(!int.TryParse(splitVal[3].Replace("b=","").Trim(), out intVal)) 
            intVal = 0;
        this.b = intVal;            
    }

    public string ParseToString() 
    {
        return "l=" + this.l + "; r=" + this.r + "; t=" + this.t + "; b=" + this.b + "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to use a regex in this case:

```
var position = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
var match = Regex.Match(position, @"l=(-?\d+); r=(-?\d+); t=(-?\d+); b=(-?\d+)");
if (!match.Success)
    throw new Exception("invalid data");

var l = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[1].Value);
var r = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);
var t = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[3].Value);
var b = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[4].Value);

// modify the values as you like, for example: t -= 75; b -=75;

var newPosition = $"l={l}; r={r}; t={t}; b={b}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Position structure, like this:

```
public struct Position
{
    public int Left { get; private set; }
    public int Top { get; private set; }
    public int Right { get; private set; }
    public int Bottom { get; private set; }

    public Position(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Right = right;
        Bottom = bottom;
    }

    public Position(string positionText)
    {
        string pattern = @"(?=l=(?<left>[\d\-]+))|(?=t=(?<top>[\d\-]+))|(?=r=(?<right>[\d\-]+))|(?=b=(?<bottom>[\d\-]+))";
        Match match = Regex.Match(positionText, pattern);
        int left = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["left"].Value);
        int top = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["top"].Value);
        int right = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["right"].Value);
        int bottom = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups["bottom"].Value);
        Left = left;
        Top = top;
        Right = right;
        Bottom = bottom;
    }

    public Position Move(int leftDelta = 0, int topDelta=0, int rightDelta=0, int bottomDelta = 0)
    {
        return new Position(Left + leftDelta, Top + topDelta, Right + rightDelta, Bottom + bottomDelta);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("l={0}; r={1}; t={2}; b={3}", Left, Right, Top, Bottom);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Position oldPosition = new Position("l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480");
Position newPosition = oldPosition.Move(topDelta: -75, bottomDelta: -75);
string newPositionText = newPosition.ToString();
```

Comment: Why would you perform `Regex.Match` four separate times?  That's incredibly inefficient.

Comment: That was to allow to give parameters in any order, but a positive lookahead would be better. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple method can do the trick:

```
public static string ModifyPositions(string positionsInput, int displacement)
    {
        string input = "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480";
        var pattern = @"(t|b)=(-?\d+)";
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);
        var matches = regex.Matches(input);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            input = input.Replace(match.Groups[2].Value, (int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value) + displacement).ToString());
        }

        return input;
    }
```

In your case displacement is -75, positionsInput is "l=50; r=190; t=-430; b=-480"